# c# Design Pattern for multiple property calculation

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I have a list of MyClass and each item in this list has MyComplexObject list.

I have to derive/calculate values in MyClass like IsXyz, Rate etc... and then use these values to derive/calculate IsABC, IsValid etc. for each item in ComplexClass list item in MyClass.

Now deriving IsXyz or Rate or IsABC or IsValid have their own logic which in itself complex and hence need separate classes.

Which design pattern could be a best fit here?

```
class MyClass
    {
        public bool IsXyz { get; set; }
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public List<ComplexClass> MyComplexObject { get; set; }
        public double Rate { get; set; }
// Many more such props
    }

    class ComplexClass
    {
        public bool IsABC { get; set; }
        public decimal ID { get; set; }
        public double IsValid { get; set; }
// Many more such props
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: if the properties are going to be the same and the calculation method is going to vary, you can have an interface and have have classes implement with custom calculation. And have a DI way of loading custom implementation at runtime.

Comment: Props are diff and calc method is also diff depending on the prop.

Comment: common properties can be kept in base class and you can inherit. u can have virtual members and override. but if there are not much in common then it is not a good idea.

Comment: I think I would try to have a reference to `MyClass` from `ComplexClass`, perhaps a property like `Parent`, to more easily read *from* `MyClass` from within `ComplexClass` instead of assigning *to* `ComplexClass` from within `MyClass`. Also, as @Aravind says, consider rationalizing out `ComplexClass` to a base class and various implementations, if there are sveral patterns.

Comment: That would duplicate all of the props of MyClass for each ComplexClass, because for a given set of props in MyClass there can be thousands of ComplexClass items in MyComplexObject.

Comment: not new instances of `MyClass`, references from `ComplexClass` to its parent `MyClass`, ie virtual property